# What audio formats are necessary for cross-browser support?

Tags: jquery, html, flash, audio

Alright, I'm using [jPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org/) in a website, which is a cross-platform/cross-browser jQuery solution for audio and video playback on a website.  On my website, I will have users upload files either in MP3 or OGG format.  I wonder though... in order to truly stay 100% stable on any browser or platform, wouldn't I need to support a corresponding OGG for every MP3 uploaded (and vice-versa)?  I know jPlayer uses HTML5 when it can and will fall back to Flash when necessary, but I didn't know if you need to have that file in both formats to have it play everywhere.

If I need both file formats then I suppose I'd have to convert the file to the other format using a server-side conversion.  If I need just one format... then wouldn't that be just dandy!  So my question is, do I need to convert?  Or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For xbrowser support, a format must be supplied that works in both HTML5 and Flash.
>   Optional additional formats may be supplied to increase xbrowser HTML5 support.

I would say it is neccesary to provide at least a mp3 and ogg format to ensure that everything runs perfectly on each platform. There are many tools to convert a mp3 file to ogg, e.g. [ffmpeg-php](http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, I could also just use ffmpeg at command line, couldn't I?  I would there be a security issue in doing such?

Comment: Exactly! Make sure that PHP safe_mode is running and you should check that the given file is a real file before trying to encode too.